# Run multiple command lines in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5

I need to run multiple Ruby commands inside docker. What I normally do from SSH is:

```
docker exec -it containername bundle exec rails c
```

And then run my command. In this case:

```
SharedAccess.create(room_id: 56, user_id: 2)
```

The thing is I need to run multiple commands with different user_id's.

```
SharedAccess.create(room_id: 56, user_id: 3)
SharedAccess.create(room_id: 56, user_id: 4)
SharedAccess.create(room_id: 56, user_id: 5)
```

What I normally would do in shell is creating a script, pasting all the lines one below the other in there and then just run it.
I want to find a way to create something like a script with all the lines in there and then run it from rake (inside docker).

Comment: you can just put the code lines you want to run inside a rake task, there doesn't need to be another script.

Comment: Ok that actually works! Thank you. And what about making it a script?

Comment: Definitely put it in a task and run like docker exec -it containername bundle exec rake migrate:shared_access .

Answer (score 3):

create a file `somefile.rake` in your lib/tasks directory:

```
namespace :migrate do
  desc "create some SharedAccess"
  task shared_access: :environment do
    SharedAccess.create(room_id: 56, user_id: 3)
    SharedAccess.create(room_id: 56, user_id: 4)
    SharedAccess.create(room_id: 56, user_id: 5)
  end
end
```

and now you can run
`docker exec containername bundle exec rake migrate:shared_access`

Comment: Rake tasks usually have a `.rake` extension even if they are just Ruby. This one should probably be called `migrate.rake` so it makes sense which task(s) it defines.

Comment: Thank you @Spikie but I am very new into Ruby / Docker. How should I create the somefile.rake in lib/tasks inside Docker?

Comment: There are a lot of ways to do this.                                                                         
    1.The simplest way is get a bash shell in container: ```docker exec -it containername sh``` and run ```vim lib/tasks/somefile.rb```.                                     
    2.If your container is generated by Dockerfile.you can create somefile.rake in your project,and run ```docker build .``` in app root directory,and then somefile.rake should exist in your container.